# How to add labels to tag release in GitHub?

Tags: github, label, release, git-tag

I have released a tag. I can see a label called **"latest"** on the release.

Can i add more labels on the same release?
if so how to do it?

I don't find any option to add labels to a release.

Thanks in advance

Reference image to where i wanna add label

[image: Latest label on release]